# RSS aggregator that outputs re-formatted RSS?

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a way to pull in a few RSS feeds, then spit out a composite feed. However, we need to strip some info (e.g. the output feed should only contain the title of each item), as well as limit dates/times etc. Also, it would be useful to only output the most recent 10 entries. Is there such a tool, or will I have to hack one together myself?

Comment: For the record, this is in the context of a display system we're configuring; it seemed slightly more at home here than either superuser or stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to host it yourself you might see if Yahoo pipes http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/ will work for you.